# Fixing three aesthetic issues regarding an html input, select, and button

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

Currently my code displays:

[image]

where the first (squared) box is an `<input>` while the second (rectangled) box is a `<select>`. I'm having the following issues:

1. The inputted text is not showing in the `<input>` box; similarly, the chosen option is not showing in the `<select>` box.
2. The green button should be centered, which I've tried doing with the lines `text-align: center` and `align-content: center`, with no avail.
3. When hovering over the button this one should become 1.1 times larger for which I've used the line `transition: scale(1.1)`, yet the line seems to have no effect.

---

```
<template>
  <div id="food-info">
    <div class="division center">
      <h3 class="division">Banana</h3>
      <h4 class="division">Serving size</h4>
      <input class="division quant-input" />
      <select class="division quant-sizes">
        <option>100g</option>
        <option>large</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div>
      <button class="add-entry center">Add to Diary</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<style scoped>
.center {
  text-align: center;
  align-content: center;
}
.division {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 1rem 1rem;
}
.quant-input {
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
}
.quant-sizes {
  height: 10px;
  width: 80px;
  top: 40px;
}
.add-entry {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: #4caf50;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}
.add-entry:hover {
  transition: scale(1.1);
}
</style>
```

Comment: The `text-align: center` should be on the `<div>` that contains the button, not on the button itself.

Comment: Also note that no current browser supports scoped CSS by default, and the feature has been removed from the specifications.

Comment: @Pointy I'm using chrome and it works fine; perhaps it's because I'm using Vue? And you are right about the ```center```. That solved issue 2.

Comment: Well it was removed from the code base years ago. `<style scoped>` does not cause an error, but it does the same thing as `<style banana>`, which is nothing.

Answer (score 1):

there is several mistakes in your codes:

1. you set padding on `.division` and there is no space for your content in `input` element and `select` element
2. `align-items`(not `-content`) center elements vertically if you want to center any element horizontally you should do this:

```css
.parent-elmnt {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

3. you should use `transform` not `transition`

```css
.add-entry:hover {
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

check this :

```css
      /* add this codes to variables.css */

      :root {
        --primary-color: #4caf50;
        --text-color: #fff;
      }

      /* add this code to your reset.css */

      :root {
        font-size: 16px;
      }

      * {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        font: inherit;
      }

      h1 {
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.25rem
      }

      button {
        outline: none;
      }

      /* add this code to utilities.css */

      .p-2 {
        padding: 0.5rem;
      }

      .p-4 {
        padding: 1rem;
      }

      .mb-4 {
        margin-bottom: 1rem;
      }

      .flex {
        display: flex;
      }

      .column {
        flex-direction: column;
      }

      .justify-center {
        justify-content: center;
      }

      .justify-space-between {
        justify-content: space-between;
      }

      .w-full {
        width: 100%;
      }

      .rounded-pill {
        border-radius: 500rem;
      }

      /* add this codes to your components.css */
      .btn {
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: var(--text-color);
        border: none;
        padding: 0.5rem;
        transition: all 0.5s;
      }

      .btn:hover {
        transform: scale(1.02);
      }
      
      /* then import all of these file in your main css */
```

```html
    <div class="p-4 mb-4 flex column justify-center">
      <h1 class="mb-4">Banana</h1>

      <div class="flex justify-space-between">
        <h2>Serving size</h2>
        <div>
          <input class="p-2" />
          <select class="p-2">
            <option>100g</option>

            <option>large</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="p-4">
      <button class="btn w-full rounded-pill">Add to Diary</button>
    </div>
```

Comment: Regarding 1, if I remove the padding then all elements will lay together in a single line with no space in between. Is there a way to prevent this, or alternatively, to keep the padding while finding space for the input/choices? That being said, 2 and 3 work perfectly (:

Comment: if you want space between elements you should use `margin`

Comment: soon I edit this answer and add better code

Comment: @Sam check my code I think it's a better way to write your style. this code is scalable